# Magento 2: How can I verify native captcha in a form via an ajax call to controller only?

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax, captcha

I have an ajax customer registration form with native captcha. I am already returning ajax based response against other field validations. Only thing left is Captcha validation.

Please tell me how can I validate this captcha remaining with in the form posted controller.

Answer (score 0):

So whenever you are sending a call to ajax controller then you have to make a another call to check the validation for that you have to create a plugin. 
This plugin will execute when you call your controller.

Assuming you already have a controller 
Controller/Ajax/Login.php - This is my controller

Create etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
    * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Usermg\Register\Controller\Ajax\Login">
        <plugin name="login_ajax" type="Usermg\Register\Plugin\AjaxLogin" sortOrder="50" />
    </type>


    </config>
```

In this type name is your controller name and inside tag is for plugin name and plugin path

Create Plugin/AjaxLogin.php

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Usermg\Register\Plugin;

    use Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data as CaptchaHelper;
    use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

    class AjaxLogin
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $helper;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
         */
        protected $sessionManager;

        /**
         * @var JsonFactory
         */
        protected $resultJsonFactory;


        protected $captchaStringResolver;

        /**
         * @param CaptchaHelper $helper
         * @param SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
         * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
         * @throws \RuntimeException
         */
        public function __construct(
            CaptchaHelper $helper,
            SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager,
            JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
             \Magento\Captcha\Observer\CaptchaStringResolver $captchaStringResolver //
        ) {
            $this->helper = $helper;
            $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->captchaStringResolver = $captchaStringResolver;
        }

        /**
         * @param \Usermg\Register\Controller\Ajax\Login $subject
         * @param \Closure $proceed
         * @return $this
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
         */
        public function aroundExecute(
            \Usermg\Register\Controller\Ajax\Login $subject,
            \Closure $proceed
        ) {
            $formId = 'captcha_login'; 
            $captchaModel = $this->helper->getCaptcha($formId);
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->captchaStringResolver->resolve($subject->getRequest(), $formId))) {
                $this->sessionManager->setCustomerFormData($subject->getRequest()->getPostValue());
                $response = [
                    'errors' => true,
                    'message' => __('Incorrect CAPTCHA.')
                ];
                return $result->setData($response);
            }        
            return $proceed();
        }
    }
```

This plugin will inject when your controller run your execute funtion aroundExecute - this will send error if catcha is wrong and will stop the further process. 
2) if captcha is fine then it will jump to your controller logic.

Hope this will help.